# Mongoose: From an array of objects in model, extract value of a property as array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a schema of users, contains books, and I want to get the book list of one user

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    gender: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    books: [{
        id: String
        title: String
        author: String
    }]

});
```

For example,

```
[{id: "1",
  gender: "Male",
  firstName: "Alan",
  lastName: "Brown",
  books: [
    { id: "ISN001",
      title: "Programming From Beginer to Give Up",
      author: "Someone"
    },
    { id: "ISN002",
      title: "Introduction to Databases",
      author: "BetaCat"
    }
  ]
},
{ id: "2",
  gender: "Female",
  firstName: "Cynthia",
  lastName: "Durand",
  books: [
    { id: "ISN003",
      title: "How to Play with Your Cat",
      author: "UrCat"
    },
    { id: "ISN004",
      title: "Greek Mythology",
      author: "Heracles"
    }
  ]
}]
```

I can get the user id by req.params.user_id, and return the book list array of this user. 
For example, I want `["Programming From Beginer to Give Up","Introduction to Databases"]` if I get user_id 1. 
I try to do this by

```
var getBookList = (req, res) => {
    User.find(req.params.user_id, (err, user) => {
        var books = user.map((item) => {return item.title;});
    });
}
```

But doesn't work, because map is not a function for user.

Comment: And I try to use map from the answer of this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User is an object, you want to map the books array inside it.

```
const books = user.books.map(book => book.title)
```

Also change `find` to `findById` as you only want 1 record.

When in doubt put a console.log in there and see if the value is what you expect.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'books' of undefined. It seems that the user I find can not do that

Comment: I just noticed you're using `.find` which is for multiple records so it will return an array of users with one inside it, change to `findById` since you are finding by ID (or `findOne` if you weren't). Never use queries for multiple documents when looking for a single one as this is inefficient too.

Answer (score 0):

```
User.find({id:req.params.user_id}, (err, user) => {
    var books = user.map((item) => {return item.title;});
});
```

Try the above one

Comment: no error for this one :D, but empty array output ;-(